# Capistrano error/warning when not using sudo

Tags: capistrano, sudo

When I run deploy:setup and deploy:update I see embedded in the output (in multiple places)

```
*** [err :: domain.com] sudo
*** [err :: domain.com] :
*** [err :: domain.com] no tty present and no askpass program specified
*** [err :: domain.com]
```

Yet, everything deploys fine since I have `:use_sudo, false`.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar message with :use_sudo, true. The solution was to add this to ~/.caprc:

```
default_run_options[:pty] = true
```

(Alternatively you can insert in the Capfile or config/deploy.rb)

It's not obvious why you're seeing the message, but I would hope the above technique would at least stop those messages appearing for you.